# What should I do if a user completely rewrites their answer, making all comments and votes irrelevant?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

I asked a question and I got an answer that didn't work for various reasons.

After quite extensive discussion in comments and a downvote, the user decided to edit their answer by deleting all proposed solutions and writing an entirely different one.

The problem is that now there is an answer with a bunch of comments and votes which do not apply to it at all. (Well, there is only my vote which I can change but let's extrapolate it to a general case.)

(Link to the answer in question: *[Gradle is unable to find zip artifact in composite build if java plugin is applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57272576/gradle-is-unable-to-find-zip-artifact-in-composite-build-if-java-plugin-is-appli/57462135#57462135)*)

In my opinion, in such situation, the user should create a new answer and delete/leave the old one.

Do you agree?

Should I do something with this? Flag the answer? Or is it acceptable?

Comment: Remove your comments? If I would've been the answerer I would've removed the answer and added a new one. But now it is too late, if the answer helps you then it should definetly stay, clean up the comments and move on.

Comment: @JonasWilms Well, I could but then other comments would make even less sense. I guess I could flag them to being removed. Still, there is an issue with votes.

Comment: an answer is debated and even downvoted so the author decides to edit it. Well... that sounds like an absolute win.

Comment: We are talking about one (!) single downvote right?

Comment: @JonasWilms In this case yes but I asked about general case. Let's assume more people have voted.

Comment: Flag comments as "no longer needed" and revise your vote, if needed. That seems like the appropriate action here. Although if an answerer wants to completely re-write an answer, it also seems appropriate for them to post a new one.

Comment: If an answer changes substantially to where the votes are no longer "relevant", over time the votes will work out. People will stop upvoting it (or perhaps downvote it) and the other answers will be voted higher. Short term, other than what the other people here have suggested, not much to do.

Comment: @Gimby Well, if you assume that the new answer is better then yeah. It still doesn't meet conditions from the question :( That's an entirely different problem, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can custom flag so a mod cleans up the whole comment thread.

Reverse/undo your vote, if you feel it is appropriate.

About the other votes, do not mind them at all. The score of a post is supposed to be an aggregate of the opinion of many users as time goes by and they find the post.

If a post is edited, it is natural that votes after certain edit might differ from votes that came before the edit. In the long run, hopefully enough users will see the newer version and the "final" score will more accurately reflect the quality of the post.

That a poster reacts to comments and/or votes is a good thing. Some users will see the edits in time and may rectify their votes (and maybe even delete their comments), particularly on an answer if they are keeping tabs on a fresher question.

But if not, time heals all wounds and brings more votes.

Comment: I agree completely - but It's a shame that users don't get pinged when a question they voted on changes, though. I wonder how many people revisit a question 10+ minutes after they've cast their vote?

Comment: On newer answers (which is the subject of this question) it's not so unusual to stay on the question for a while. Most users getting to a *new* question are looking for things to answer, so they may spend some time on the question and see the edit. Personally, I wouldn't want to receive notifications from posts I voted on. No please no.

Comment: @lewis honestly that would be a waste of time, most edits aren't substantial. And if so, further visitors will upvote, just as Yivi said.

Comment: @Lewis trust me - not a lot. I do. I try to monitor anything I've downvoted for about 24 hours for changes (checking few times over the period) and a couple of times a month I go over my recent-ish downvotes to see if they've changed. A lot rarely do or they just deleted. But of the posts that have changed and have addressed any concerns that led to downvotes, there is barely a change in the votes.